# Writing a protobuf object to GCS

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I am making a dataflow (java api) which will write protobuf object to gcs. Can anyone please help me with how to do this. A sample of code or something would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-221 has some thoughts on this.

Wrap AvroIO in a Composite PTransform:

- Avro schema is just a single byte[].
- On read, convert from byte[] to
  the user's proto.
- On write, convert from proto to byte[].

In this way, ProtoIO would just be a simple wrapper for AvroIO.Read+ParDo (read) or ParDo+AvroIO.Write.